# PHP echo variable from include before include

Tags: php, html, include, title

My index.php looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title?></title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Hi, this is my homepage. I'll include some text below.</p>

<?php
include "myfile.php";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

"myfile.php" e.g. includes the following:

```
<?php
$title = "Hi, I'm the title tag…";
?>
<p>Here's some content on the site I included!</p>
```

The `<p>` gots outputted but the `<title>` tag stays blank.

How can I reach to get `$title` from the included site and also show the included content inside the `<body>` tag?

Comment: you use echo $title to show in screen.

Comment: What were you trying to do. `include` is used to include files. Make your question a bit more clear.

Comment: Your file had to included before using the `$title` variable.

Comment: @Sasikumar, updated my question. Yes, but I need to include it inside the `<body>` tag, and not before `title` tag. How to do that?

Comment: You probably can … sort of … by doing some nasty messing about with output buffering then editing the buffer before releasing it to the browser … but the real solution to this problem is to better separate your data from your templates (the MVC pattern is a good one to look at).

Comment: I think your architecture is not very good. You could try to use either some template engine (for example Smarty http://www.smarty.net/) where you can assign the title per page easily and then just compile the output for the HTML page.

Comment: You could also think about saving global and important variables in `$_SESSION[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
index.php

<?php
// Turn on the output buffering so that nothing is printed when we include myfile.php
ob_start();

// The output from this line now go to the buffer
include "myfile.php"; 

// Get the content in buffer and turn off the output buffering
$body_content = ob_get_contents();    

ob_end_clean();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title?></title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Hi, this is my homepage. I'll include some text below.</p>
<?php
echo $body_content; // Now, we have the output of myfile.php in a variable, what on earth will prevent us from echoing it?
?>
</body>
</html>
```

`myfile.php` is unchanged.

P.S: As Noman suggested, you can first `include 'myfile.php';` at the beginning of `index.php`, then `echo $content;` inside body tag, and change `myfile.php` into something like this:

```
<?php
$title = "Hi, I'm the title tag"
ob_start();
?>

<p>Here's some content on the site I included!</p>

<?php
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Comment: Your own solution works. But, how does it work. Can you explain that to me, please?

Comment: When you include `myfile.php`, the html part is outputted. I use ob_* function to capture it into a variable instead of letting it be printed out, that's all.
`ob_start()` to turn the output buffering on, `ob_get_contents()` to get the string stored in buffer, `ob_end_clean()` to clean the output buffer then turn off the output buffering.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Have a nice day!

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/3XgxNj) is an example. Hope this help.
P.S: Oh, didn't notice your comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do it:

**index.php**

```
<?php
include "myfile.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title?></title>
</head>
<body>

<p><?php $content; ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

**myfile.php**

```
<?php
$title = "Hi, I'm the title tag…";
$content = "Here's some content on the site I included!";
?>
```

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean. Could you embed this in my code, please!?

Comment: You mean to say that you want to show `<p>Here's some content on the site I included!</p>` into body ? right ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: You should have to do just like this `$con = "<p>Here's some content on the site I included!</p>";` and then echo this into a body. This is the only way.

Comment: You mean: I'll include two variables, `$title` and `$content`. `echo $title;` is in the html title tag and `echo $content;` is inside the html body. Right?

Comment: Yes, That is the way and also I updated this into my answer box please check it again.

Comment: That's an good idea but I would have to escape the whole code, this may be some hundred lines of code. `LYF_HKN`'s solution works.

Comment: You did not mention about that. Well, the thing is your problem solved. That the point.